# How to create an application in Java EE which listens for an incoming request on TCP/IP socket?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tcp, sockets, listen

I need to have a business logic running inside GlassFish 2.1 Appserver, which listens for inbound TCP connections and serves them. I feel that this kind of task is not really fit inside the appserver - maybe I should publish web service interfaces, etc, but I can't, at least not directly for the client.

The client will connect to my app via TCP, and will exchange plain-text commands and responses.

Do I need an external mediator program which translates the client TCP to rmi calls? Or does Java EE has native support for listening on sockets and doing direct I/O on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JCA 1.5 is the standard solution for this kind of tasks, but it's not the easiest part of Java EE, and you won't find tons of examples to get you started.
You could have a look at lifecycle modules if you don't mind a Glassfish specific solution, and [JAFS](http://www.sbbi.net/site/jafs/index.html), an ftp server that can be embedded in the 'fish probably contains a lot of inspiration to get you started.

Comment: Thank you, the lifecycle module seems fine for now, and maybe will try JCA later.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using BPEL - the openesb solution has bpel modules for listening via sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I have used somewhat similar solution as per my need. Might be this can help someone here around.

You need to Start a new Socket Port on server start up or on application load. I used @scheduler annotation whereas you can use listener based solution as well.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
public void startListenerPort() {
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(9999);
// do some stuff here
}
```

Just make sure that you have allowed TCP traffic on the port that you have assigned to the Socket (Firewall Settings).

In this way, you can have TCP traffic on port 9999, where as your app server will continue to run on different port as normal.

Comment: -1. http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_0-fr-spec-ejbcore.pdf?AuthParam=1540507489_8296fcddc15d6af8a10ede3d2d129c53 From the EJB3.0 spec directly (section 21.1.2): `An enterprise bean must not attempt to listen on a socket, accept connections on a socket, or use a socket for multicast.`

Answer (score -1):

JavaEE has no explicit support for raw socket communication, but in principle there's nothing to stop you using `java.net.Socket` directly. Glassfish may potentially block this, if the security manager is configured to restrict socket access, but that shouldn't be the case unless it's been explicitly configured that way.

Comment: -1 because the spec definitely stops you. http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_0-fr-spec-ejbcore.pdf?AuthParam=1540507489_8296fcddc15d6af8a10ede3d2d129c53 From the EJB3.0 spec directly (section 21.1.2): `An enterprise bean must not attempt to listen on a socket, accept connections on a socket, or use a socket for multicast.`